# Organizing a DF with unique values

Tags: r

I have a database with animal tags. Sometimes the animal lost a tag and that tag is replaced by another tag, with goes for a table like that:

```
date<- c('2018-01-01','2018-02-20','2018-10-04','2018-12-30','2019-01-03','2019-03-14','2019-05-06','2019-07-01','2019-07-25','2019-10-29','2019-11-26','2020-01-07','2020-05-04','2020-12-30')

> id_brinco_or<-c(1,5,10,20,31,3,4,13,15,12,2,65,9,93)
> id_brinco_rp<-c(2,8,15,12,13,6,28,55,65,9,80,40,93,30)
> 
> df<-data.frame(date,id_brinco_or,id_brinco_rp)
> df
         date id_brinco_or id_brinco_rp
1  2018-01-01            1            2
2  2018-02-20            5            8
3  2018-10-04           10           15
4  2018-12-30           20           12
5  2019-01-03           31           13
6  2019-03-14            3            6
7  2019-05-06            4           28
8  2019-07-01           13           55
9  2019-07-25           15           65
10 2019-10-29           12            9
11 2019-11-26            2           80
12 2020-01-07           65           40
13 2020-05-04            9           93
14 2020-12-30           93           30
>
```

What I need is creating a df with the first tag on one column and the tags associated with that tag in other columns, like that:

```
  id_brinco_un<-c(1,1,5,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,31,31,3,4)
> id_brinco<-c(2,80,8,15,65,40,12,9,93,30,13,55,6,28)
> df2<-data.frame(id_brinco_un,id_brinco)
> df2
   id_brinco_un id_brinco
1             1         2
2             1        80
3             5         8
4            10        15
5            10        65
6            10        40
7            20        12
8            20         9
9            20        93
10           20        30
11           31        13
12           31        55
13            3         6
14            4        28
```

That way I could use the df2 to treat another tables in my database to get all information of the same animal, using ifelse, %in%, match, etc.

I have some trouble with terms, I believe that concepts exists, but I don't know which words I use to find that.

I have being using *tidyverse* package, so it's easier for me, but any solution form any package is appreciated!

The DF I need to work has almost 2 million rows.
The ids are not necessarilly ascending, but in most cases are.

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer that's not really an edit to the first one. I cannot quite believe that a data scheme would not have included dates and case ID's. I think the analysis would have been much easier and there would have been the possibility of error detection. (The dates values in the second example make no sense, so I can see why they have been omitted.)

Regardless of my editorial whinging .....  If you look at the `df` dataframe and ignore the fact that `df` is also a function name,  you can see that 1) you need the position in the "_or" column where a value in the "_rp" column exists. Then 2) you want to replace the value in that position with the value of the "or" column in the row number of the of the matching "rp" value. And 3) since you want to track the transitions over multiple such transitions, you will need to do this process as many times as the most frequently replaced tag changed on a particular entity (animal?).

Step 1:

```
 with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )) # but NA's cannot be used as indices
#[1] 11 NA  9 10  8 NA NA NA 12 13 NA NA 14 NA
na.omit( with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))
#[1] 11  9 10  8 12 13 14
```

Step 2: (get the positions from the first part of step 1)

```
 grep("\\d", with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or ))  )
[1]  1  3  4  5  9 10 13
```

Step 3: replace values in "or" column (repeatedly until there is no change, step 1 indices on LHS and step 2 indices on RHS

```
> id_brinco_or[na.omit( with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))] <- id_brinco_or[grep("\\d", with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))]
> id_brinco_or
 [1]  1  5 10 20 31  3  4 31 10 20  1 15 35 72
> id_brinco_or[na.omit( with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))] <- id_brinco_or[grep("\\d", with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))]
> id_brinco_or
 [1]  1  5 10 20 31  3  4 31 10 20  1 10 20 35
> id_brinco_or[na.omit( with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))] <- id_brinco_or[grep("\\d", with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))]
> id_brinco_or
 [1]  1  5 10 20 31  3  4 31 10 20  1 10 20 20
> id_brinco_or[na.omit( with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))] <- id_brinco_or[grep("\\d", with(df, match(id_brinco_rp, id_brinco_or )))]
> id_brinco_or
 [1]  1  5 10 20 31  3  4 31 10 20  1 10 20 20  # No change, stop.

> df2 <- data.frame(id_brinco_or, id_brinco_rp)
> df2 <- df2[ order(df2$id_brinco_or) , ]
> df2
   id_brinco_or id_brinco_rp
1             1            2
11            1           80
6             3           12
7             4           28
2             5            8
3            10           15
9            10           65
12           10           85
4            20           35
10           20           72
13           20           93
14           20          120
5            31           47
8            31           55
```

It's kind of amusing to me that this problem is isomorphic to a problem I had back in 1989 and failed to solve despite have a contract SAS programmer available. I certainly would not have been able to solve it with the SAS knowledge I ever acquired, so I really cannot blame my contractor's failure on his lack of skill. Rather I blame it on SAS's lack of expressivity.

Comment: @IRTM Edited. I made two mistakes there: forget to run the date row and forget to add the date vector on data.frame function (what would warned about the first mistake). The case ID is not necessarilly ascending, so  maybe the date is necessary for sorts things up. I 'm telling maybe because what I really need is a "translate" table that I can use to transform several ids to one unique id, so the order does not matter, I think.

Comment: I assumed that a case ID wouldn't be used for anything except splitting into groups of lines that were related. And then ordering within those groups by date (since tag ids are "not necessarily ascending". Again, writing code with clear examples of a starting point is futile. I don't see how I can do anything more at this point.

Comment: @IRTM You done enough. Thank you for your kindness.